# Black screen after login in Gnome

Tags: fedora, gnome, nvidia, cinnamon, graphic-card

I made a fresh install of Fedora 28 (kernel 4.17) on my Thinkpad P50 with NVidia Quadro M1000M. I have had trouble with external screen (did not work) so I decided to install proprietary NVidia drivers.

In the end I ended up with working environment once I set BIOS to use discrete graphics only (not hybrid), but after ~2 hours the system got stuck (when I tried to install xrandr to adjust brightness) and I hard-rebooted. Since then I can't login into Gnome; both screens turn black and I can only see the cursor.
I have successfully installed Cinnamon and that works. However since I am more used to Gnome I'd prefer to be able to use it.

Reinstalling (`dnf remove gdm && dnf install gdm`) did not help. I have disabled Wayland in `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` but to no avail - I somehow even lost the 'Gnome Classic' option in the login screen.

I've tried to get back to Nouveau but I am stuck on laptop-screen only on 1024x768 - and the driver is not black-listed in any file in `/etc/modprobe.d/`. I have tried both 390 and 396 drivers (compiled myself) and 396 from negativo17, same result.

What configuration could get broken?

Comment: I think maybe we have the same issue. Can you try switching to non graphical mode (Ctrl + alt + F2) and then back to graphical mode (Ctrl + Alt + F1)? On CentOS, this allows me to bypass this black screen. Does it help?

Comment: Regrettably not. From non-graphical mode I can only login & `pkill gnome` which gets be back to the login screen.